# How to check whether the user has permission?

Tags: mysql, permissions, roles, user-permissions, user-roles

I have two tables (users and permissions). How can I check whether a user has pemission? in this case permission for editing topics

1 is the admin account

TABLES:
**users** (id, username, acc_type)
          (1, mirso, 1)

**permissions** (id, name, description, acc_type, permission_key)
                (1, Topic edit, some text, 1, edit_topic)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [SHOW GRANTS Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html)

> SHOW GRANTS displays only the privileges granted explicitly to the
>   named account. Other privileges might be available to the account, but
>   they are not displayed. For example, if an anonymous account exists,
>   the named account might be able to use its privileges, but SHOW GRANTS
>   will not display them.

You may try like this:

```
Show grants for myuser;
```

**EDIT:-**

Not very sure about this but you may give it a try like this:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('Database_Address','database_user','database_password');
if ($db === false)  {
  die("mysql_connect error: " . mysql_error());
}
$selected = mysql_select_db('Database', $db); 
if ($selected === false)  {
  die("mysql_select_db error: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: how to do this using PHP PDO ??

Comment: @user3026971:- Updated my answer. Although not very sure if that helps! :(

Comment: example of what I want to do, I hope you understand my question

if (if the user has permission for editing theme) {
     / / PHP PDO prepare
} else {
    die ('error);
}